# the poincaré metric of $B_R=\{z: 1<|z|<R\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here I want to find the $Poincar\acute e$ of $B_R=\{z:1<|z|<R\}$.

So the firet step I need to do is to find the covering space of $B_R$, then we can caculate the the $Poincar\acute e$ through the covering map, but I have some difficulty to find the covering map, I know $B_R=\{z:1<|z|<R\}$ is conformal isomorphism to a rectangle, the problem then becomes the conformal mapping of the rectangle to the unit circle or upper half plane .